# Perl basic questions

Tags: perl

1. In Unix shell script we check the exit status of the previous command using the value of `$?` where zero equals success.  How can I do it in Perl?
2. When I run `perl -V` I see some paths listed in `@INC`.  How do I add new paths to `@INC`?
3. How can I set the order of arguments in the `GetOptions` function? I want `-email` to be the first argument and if it's given as second argument it should fail.

   ```
   GetOptions(
       'nemail' => sub {$ENV{EMAIL} = "Y"},
       'arg'    => \$help
   );
   ```
4. What is the difference between the extensions `.pl` and `.pm`? When do I need to use the `.pm` extension?
5. When I write `use File::Copy`, where is the code located? Which enviroment variables does `use` access?

Comment: Arav, almost all of these five questions are unrelated to each other. In the future it would be better to [ask a seperate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for each topic.

Answer (score 8):

1. External commands are launched with the [`system` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), it also sets the [child error variable `$?`/`$CHILD_ERROR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24CHILD_ERROR). Instead of doing those checks yourself, use [`autodie`](http://p3rl.org/autodie#system/exec):

   ```
   require IPC::System::Simple;
   use autodie qw(:all);
   system([0], 'foobar-command', '--option', '--yet-another-option');
   # 0 is allowed as an exit status, others will throw an exception
   ```

   Internal programming constructs, e.g. subroutines from modules, use error checking that goes beyond from what you know from shell programming. There is more than one way to do it. Most of the type, success and failure is signalled by the return value of a function, often `undef` means failure, e.g. by reading the [documentation for `File::Copy`](http://p3rl.org/File::Copy#RETURN) we learn that the return value is 0 for failure and also the usual other error variable  is set.

   ```
   use English qw($OS_ERROR)
   use File::Copy qw(mv);
   my $source = '/does_not_exist';
   my $destination = '/tmp';
   unless (mv($source, $destination)) {
       warn "Move from $source to $destination failed: $OS_ERROR";
   }
   ```

   Another possibility is exceptions. You have to learn this in detail: chapter 13 of [PBP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735/) and chapter 11 of [EPP](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Effective-Perl-Programming-Ways-to-Write-Better-More-Idiomatic-Perl-2E/9780321496942.page).

   ```
   use Try::Tiny;
   my $string;
   try {
       $string = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $octets_buffer, Encode::FB_CROAK)
   } catch {
       warn "Decoding failed: $_";
   }
   ```
2. - [`perlvar` `@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC)
   - [`perlfaq8` How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-%28%40INC%29-at-runtime%3f)
   - [`perlrun` `-I`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A-I%2A_directory_) and [`perlrun` `PERL5LIB`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5LIB)
   - [`lib`](http://p3rl.org/lib)
3. It is designed so that arguments can be in random order. Why do you want it like that? There is a configuration setting called [`require_order`](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long#require_order), but it is not exactly what you want.
4. `.pl` indicates a Perl library, most like a collection of subroutines, ready to be included via [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). This is from more than 10 years ago. People on Windows also like to give this extension to plain Perl programs because the operating system is so much extension centric and does not work comfortably with files without extensions.

   `.pm` indicates a [Perl module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module#Further_reading). A module is just a library that follows a few additional conventions. This is from the Perl 5 era.
5. `File::Copy` is translated to the file name `File/Copy.pm` which is in one of the paths in your `@INC`, for details again see [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). On my system it would be in `/usr/lib/perl5`, e.g. `/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/File/Copy.pm`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  nope. Am asking about Checking the return value of any command in perl. if i do a FILE:MOVE command  or any other command how can i check the exit status whether it was successful. In UNIX shell script we can check $?. In perl is the exit status 0 denotes success like in shell script.  
 Saw the wikipedia site. use Hello::World;  Is the World word is require here. also does the "Hello" word should be the same name as file name.   Normally in java package we have the directory name in the package name. require_order needs to be set in GET_OPTIONS COMMAND?